# Next.js HMR doesn't work when external react and react-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have an application which required `window.React` and `window.ReactDOM`, so i modify the webpack externals field in **next.config.js** like this:

```js
// next.config.js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack(config, { isServer }) {
    if (!isServer) {
      config.externals = {
        next: 'next',
        react: 'React',
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
      }
    }
    return config;
  }
}
```

But when i do this, the page can't hot reload when editing code. And there is no warning or error in the Chrome console panel. Only when i manually refresh the page, the latest code can work as well.

Reproduce repositry: https://github.com/MrKou47/nextjs-hmr-notwork-demo

Comment: You're using the [production version](https://github.com/MrKou47/nextjs-hmr-notwork-demo/blob/master/pages/_app.tsx#L8-L9) of React/ReactDOM. Use the [development](https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html) version and it'll work. That said, not sure why you want/need to externalize these dependencies... On that note, you'll need to use the production version when you compile for production.

Comment: @MattCarlotta Thanks! And my application has a plugin system, which can render component by `umd.js` from unpkg.com. So i need to external react, react-dom and my component-library to the `Window`.